# Why can't I Include header files using relative path in Visual Studio code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, arduino

In Visual Studio Code, I am trying to get a very basic ESP Arduino project to compile.

My `includePath` entry in *c_cpp_properties.json* file looks like this:

[image]

Inside the *2.7.4* folder, there is a header file *pins_arduino.h* in the following path:

```
variants/generic/pins_arduino.h
```

When I try to compile the project with the following include:

```
#include "variants/generic/pins_arduino.h"
```

it does not compile, because:

> app:1:31: fatal error: variants/generic/pins_arduino.h: No such file or directory

but when I remove the relative path and rely on the recursion of the `includePath` it compiles:

```
#include "pins_arduino.h"
```

However, the IDE does not recognize any definitions from *pins_arduino.h* file and marks all of them in red (so even the IDE does not find the definitions, it can compile, because of the recursion ** probably).

Removing the recursion from the `includePath` did not help, I still get the same compilation error when I use the relative path of the header file.

I am building using Ardiuni Extension (if I understand the concept correctly):

[image]

and I have not *task.json* file.

Why can't I include specific header files using their relative path from sub-folders? Is this some limitation in VS-Code or in C/C++ extension? I do not like using the recursion because I like to specify exactly the header I wanna include using its relative path without including every single folder in the `includePath`.

Comment: Did you also add the include path to your `tasks.json`

Comment: How are you building?

Comment: @drescherjm Arduino extension, if I understand the concept correctly.

Comment: I think someone familiar with that extension will have to help. Native `c++` building uses a `tasks.json` file.

Comment: @drescherjm, I think Arduino uses C/C++ extension (I am not sure if it is used for building), because it is mentioned as a dependency.